# Does wrapping a javascript object property in quotation marks change any functionality?

Tags: javascript, object, properties

What's the functional difference, if any, between these bits of javascript code? I want to know if wrapping the property in quotation marks changes its behavior.

```
a = {
  b: 1
}
```

```
a = {
  "b": 1
}
```

Comment: none...........

Comment: The quotes are optional unless the property name contains special characters.